# match current url path with nav path using Regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

im grabbing the current url path directory `/products/` from `www.mysite.com/products/watches`
 
 using this expression `/\/(.*?)\//`
so im trying to find the list item that has `/products/` using the expression
`<ul>
    <li><a href="/home.htm">home</a></li>`
    `<li><a href="/products/watches">watches</a></li>`
    `<li><a href="/services/watch-repair">repairs</a></li>`
    `<li><a href="/support/refund">refund</a></li>
</ul>`

this is what i have so far. [here is a better example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdavadi/XxLTQ/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is fine. Your javascript needs to be more like.

```
$('ul li a[href^="'+urlmatch[0] +'"]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');      
});
```

The code finds each link starting with your regex and marks it as active.

Comment: wow! I have allot of learning to do . It took my hours just to come up with that and you found the solution in less than two minutes thank you for your help.